# I'm having trouble in decoupling this set of two differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have the following set of equations:

$$\left(\frac{d}{dr} + \frac{k}{r}\right)g_1 + \left(\frac{m_e c^2 - E}{\hbar c}-\frac{\alpha}{r}\right)f_1=0$$

$$\left(\frac{d}{dr} - \frac{k}{r}\right)f_1 + \left(\frac{m_e c^2 + E}{\hbar c}+\frac{\alpha}{r}\right)g_1=0$$

I need to decouple then. Here's what I have tried so far:

- Differentiate the first equation, isolating the derivative in the second one and substituing it in the new equation obtained by differentiation;
- Isolate one of the functions in one equation, and substituing it in the other.

The first method led to a quite elegant and simple equation but with one yet uncoupled term. The second method led to an uncoupled equation but with really weird terms. Since I have worked out a similar problem by other means, I know the first method gave me a form somewhat correct equation, despite the coupled term, so I must be on the right track. I'd appreciate a lot for a little help on this matter.

Comment: Are you aware of the matrix method for solving systems of linear differential equations? https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SolutionsToSystems.aspx

Comment: @StephenDonovan, does that tutorial cover systems with non-constant coefficients? That's what's needed here.

Comment: My apologies, I missed the $r$'s in the coefficients

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, I will drop the subscripts on $f$ and $g$. Notice that $\left(\frac{d}{dr}+ \frac{k}{r}\right)g= r^{-k}\left(r^kg\right)'$. Similarly, $\left(\frac{d}{dr}- \frac{k}{r}\right)f= r^{k}\left(r^{-k}f\right)'$.

Define new variables $u=r^kg$ and $v=r^{-k}f$. Then the system of equations become:

\begin{align}
u'&=-\left(c_1-{\alpha \over r}\right)r^{2k}v\\
v'&=-\left(c_2+{\alpha \over r}\right)r^{-2k}u
\end{align}

We define $p(r)=-\left(c_1-{\alpha \over r}\right)r^{2k}$, and $q(r)=-\left(c_2+{\alpha \over r}\right)r^{-2k}$. So,

\begin{align}
u'&=pv\\
v'&=qu
\end{align}

This results in the decoupled second order equations:
\begin{align}
u''&=p'v+pv'=p'\frac{u'}{p}+pqu\\
v''&=q'u+qu'=q'\frac{v'}{q}+pqv
\end{align}

Comment: Whether your decoupled ODEs have explicit solutions depend on the structure of $p$ and $q$. For instance, follow this link: https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1279&context=rhumj

Comment: That was pretty clarifying. To be honest, it didn't even passed through my mind trying to define new variables, so thanks for the insight. However, I think you may have lost a global negative sign in the equations immediately after defining the u and v variables.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I fixed the sign errors.